# eric6 compile .ui file and repponsed "unknow option 'x'"

Tags: python, pyqt5

python6,pyqt5,eric6,that's my development environment.

I create a window and try to compile to .py file,
(right click the ui file and select "compile windows"
and get this:
Warning: translation file 'assistant_zh_CN' could not be loaded.
Using default.
C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\pyuic5.exe: Unknown option 'x'.

I try to compile by command line ,and sucess.
try :
pyuic5 -h,there  no -x option.
but on the help file,-x means to generate a code "app=QApplication(sys.argv)"and so on .
I'm confused

pyuic5.exe changed? and different version?
how to config eric6 to aviod '-x' option?

thanks.

Comment: You must execute: `pyuic5 your_design.ui -o your_file.py -x`

Comment: yes,that's help file tell me .but when I try:
PS D:\pyqt>  pyuic5 .\mainWindow.ui -o ui_mainWindow.py -x
Unknown option 'x'.
PS D:\pyqt>  pyuic5 .\mainWindow.ui -o ui_mainWindow.py
PS D:\pyqt>

Comment: `.\mainWindow.ui` or `mainWindow.ui`, is typo?